# PythonInterpreter Jython make transformClassesWithDexForDebug error. Where *.py file must be located?

Tags: android, python, jython, pythoninterpreter

I use Android Studio. Where *.py files must be located? Or it's problem in gradle file and that there is not enough?
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

Comment: We can't see your screen, so if you're getting an error you have to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40550117/edit) your question and put the error message in the question.

Comment: @DourHighArch sorry, edited.

Comment: I am having the same problem as you did,but will it be the size problem of the library(the jar is about 35mb).